# put command not working on windows server in fabric python

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I am trying to run the put command using fabric python.Its not working on windows server.
But it is working fine on linux server.
I am using fabric version 1.4.1.

The code is:

```
def run_windows(local_path="C:\python27\dist",remote_path="\tmp"):
    put(local_path,remote_path)
```

Below is the error message:

```
Fatal error: put() encountered an exception while uploading 'C:\python27\dist'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\fabric\operations.p
y", line 383, in put
mirror_local_mode, mode)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\fabric\sftp.py", li
ne 265, in put_dir
self.mkdir(rcontext, use_sudo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\fabric\sftp.py", li
ne 101, in mkdir`enter code here`
self.ftp.mkdir(path)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ssh\sftp_client.py", line 303, in mkdir
self._request(CMD_MKDIR, path, attr)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ssh\sftp_client.py", line 635, in _request
return self._read_response(num)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ssh\sftp_client.py", line 682, in _read_response
self._convert_status(msg)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ssh\sftp_client.py", line 710, in _convert_status
raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"

command:fab -c env.fabricrc run_windows:hosts="1.2.2.3"
```

Logs are also getting generated on server side:

```
2-02-2012 19:48:00 IP 1.6.15.1 administrator is making C:\Testing/\dist (C:\Program Files (x86)\freeSSHd\C:\Testing\dist\\dist)
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I use `put("from/path","to/path",use_sudo=True)` - it doesn't solve the problem though. With sudo it silently fails instead. fabric reports success but there is no file on the other side.